# How to modify yaml file value using bash scripting

Tags: bash, sed, yaml

I need to update values on the .yml file

For example, On below I need to modify only the version

```
name: dummyaml
description: >-
  blah blah blah.

version: 1.2.3

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.10.0 <3.0.0'
  
dependencies:
  efts: ^2.0.4
  transmogrify: ^0.4.0
  
dev_dependencies:
  test: '>=1.15.0 <2.0.0'
```

I tried this

`sed -i 's/^version:.*/version:'"$VERSION"'/' xy.yaml`
got below error

sed: 1: "xy.yaml": extra characters at the end of x command

Comment: Kindly do add your tried code as your efforts in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: while in your case you can do it with `sed` or `awk`, you should use `yq` for manipulating YAML from the shell

Comment: This might help: `yq e '.version |= "1.2.4"' <file.yaml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed 's/^\(version: \).*$/\15.6.7/' input.yml
```

- `sed 's/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/'`: PATTERN matches something from the source.  REPLACEMENT is what you now want to appear in the modified content.
- `\1`: is the content of the text in parentheses in the PATTERN.  Here, `version:`
- `^`: starts with
- `$`: ends with
- `5.6.7`: some version I put there, put your own desired value

IMPORTANT: this will only work if you only have `version: SOMETHING` in the file.  If you have more than one `version:` line, it will modify both!

Comment: Thanks ```sed 's/^\(version: \).*$/\1'"$VERSION"'/' xy.yaml``` works for me